# Can't receive images from Parse using Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I am trying to retrieve images from parse and display it to a collection view.  Xcode gives me that I can't invoke `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` with an argument type string.
I am also having an error telling me that `SingleRowCell` is not convertible to `UICollectionView`. Is my implementation of Collection View incorrect? I was able to do this using a table view.  Thank you.

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let singleCell:SingleRowCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("mySingleCell")as! SingleRowCell
        singleCell.radLabel.text = imageText [indexPath.row]
        imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if imageData != nil {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                singleCell.radImageView.image = image
            }else {
                println(error)
            }}

        return mysingleCell
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20;
    }

}
```

UPDATE

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView!.registerClass(SingleRowCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "mySingleCell")


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    var query = PFQuery(className: "rad")
    query.whereKey("uploader", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (posts: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for post in posts!{
                self.imageFiles.append(post["imageFile"]as! PFFile)
                self.imageText.append(post["imageText"]as! String)
            }


            println(self.imageFiles.count)
            self.topsCollectionView.reloadData()

        } else {
            println(error)
        }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstlly, register a class for the cell of the CollectionView:

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(SingleRowCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "mySingleCell")
```

Then, in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method,

```
let singleCell: SingleRowCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("mySingleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleRowCell

// config the cell

return singleCell
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Where do you register a class for the cell of the Collection View?

Comment: @Satsuki In the place where you init your collectionView. Somewhere like the `viewDidLoad` of your ViewController.

Comment: I have added it in ViewDidLoad however it wants the ! next to the collection view. I am still having an error with return singleCell

Comment: @Satsuki Your `SingleRowCell` should be a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`, and you should add a `!` after the collectionView. I edited my code.

Comment: Thank you found out error but app still crashing `3347.44.2/UICollectionViewController.m:171
2015-07-24 16:43:16.495 Stylist[2252:993949] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewController loadView] loaded the "4H1-83-9jU-view-Mo7-Ik-xix" nib but didn't get a UICollectionView.'`
 You can see my code I have updated the question